# python kivy widgets stacking in the bottom

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have a code that a button press should create a list and put it in list of widgets inside a window
but no matter which layout I select and how I create them(specify pos or not)
they are always created fine but all stack at the bottom of the screen

custom kv widget:

```
<item_widget@FloatLayout>
    Screen:
        size_hint:1,None
        height:25
        id:item_space
        color:18/256,47/256,82/256,0.4
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: self.color
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Label:
            id:description
            markup:True
            on_ref_press:root.open_hyperlink(args[1])
            text_size : self.size
            shorten:True
            shorten_from:'right'
            padding_x:4
            size_hint:None,1
            width:item_space.width-92
            pos:self.x,self.y
            valign:'center'
        Label:
            id:diameter
            text_size : self.size
            width:25
            halign:'center'
            size_hint:None,1
            pos:item_space.width-88,self.y
            valign:'center'
        Label:
            id:pitch
            text_size : self.size
            width:25
            halign:'center'
            size_hint:None,1
            pos:item_space.width-59,self.y
            valign:'center'
        Label:
            id:price_value
            text_size : self.size
            width:30
            halign:'center'
            size_hint:None,1
            pos:item_space.width-30,self.y
            valign:'center'
```

and this function triggers to create all the widgets in a list:

```
def put_items_inscroll(self,item_list):
    i=0
    self.ids.menu_list_scroll.clear_widgets()
    for dict in item_list:
        self.ids.menu_list_scroll.add_widget(self.constr_widget(dict))
        i+=1
```

constr_widget definition:

```
def constr_widget(self,item,y=0):
    row_instance=item_widget()
    row_instance.ids.description.text='[ref='+item['link']+']'+str(item['description'])+'[/ref]'
    row_instance.ids.diameter.text=str(item['diameter'])
    row_instance.ids.pitch.text=str(item['pitch'])
    row_instance.ids.price_value.text=str(item['calc_valPerProp'])
    row_instance.size_hint = (1, None)
    row_instance.height=25
    return row_instance
```

Im really stuck with this and nothing i did changed it
if Im only putting one widget it goes fine to the top
but if I start putting them all they stack in the bottom

screen definition:

```
    ScrollView:
        id:menu_list_scroll_window
        bar_width: 10
        effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"
        scroll_type: ['bars']
        size_hint: (None, None)
        size: (right_side.width, right_side.height-50)

        StackLayout:
            id: menu_list_scroll
            spacing: 5
            size_hint_y: None
            width: right_side.width
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'rl-tb'
```

how the widgets are stacking:
[image]

Comment: Please share your kv language definition for `menu_list_scroll`.

Comment: I did if that helps I'm really puzzled

Comment: Replace RelativeLayout with StackLayout

Comment: I tried many things and that too
but it makes no difference
if it helps I noticed its not that all the widgets are in the same place it looks like they all "try" to be in the same place on on top of each other
as can be seen in the picture I added

Comment: Basing on the name, `menu_list_scroll`, are you trying to create a scrollable menu list?

Comment: yes exactly! but I need to generate the widgets at runtime and add them to the list

Comment: Please refer to my post.

Answer (score 1):

## Menu List: ScrollView + StackLayout - orientation='rl-tb'

To create a scrollable stack of menu list with orientation from right to left, and then top to bottom,

1. In kv file, set the stacklayout's width to window's width, `width: Window.width`
2. In Python code, set the `size_hint=(None, None)` for the widgets that will be added dynamically.

Please refer to the example for details.

## Note

The attribute, `orientation: 'vertical'` is not a valid orientation for StackLayout.

[Stack Layout » orientation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.stacklayout.html#api)

> ```
> orientation
> ```
>
> Orientation of the layout.
>
> orientation is an OptionProperty and defaults to ‘lr-tb’.
>
> Valid orientations are ‘lr-tb’, ‘tb-lr’, ‘rl-tb’, ‘tb-rl’, ‘lr-bt’,
>   ‘bt-lr’, ‘rl-bt’ and ‘bt-rl’.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class RootWidget(RelativeLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        for i in range(100):
            btn = Button(text=str(i), size_hint=(None, None), width=40 + i * 5, height=90)
            self.ids.menu_list_scroll.add_widget(btn)


class TestApp(App):
    title = "Kivy Scrollable StackLayout Orientation='rl-tb' Demo"

    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window

<RootWidget>:

    ScrollView:
        bar_width: 10
        bar_color: 0, 1, 0, 1   # green
        bar_inactive_color: 1, 0, 0, 1   # red
        effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"
        scroll_type: ['bars']
        size_hint: (1, None)
        size: (Window.width, Window.height)

        StackLayout:
            id: menu_list_scroll
            spacing: 5
            size_hint_y: None
            width: Window.width
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'rl-tb'
```

## Output

[image: Img01]

Comment: First of all thank you very much for the effort I really appreciate that!
I looked over your example and incorporated it in the code to try and "reset" the errors
but still it behaves the same way
they all create fine the right shape and size and even the screen gets bigger accordingly but the only problem is that the "stacking" part doesn't happen..
I edited the question to reflect the changes I made and added every part that is related to that window I can think of
if you can think of anything that causes this 
I will most probably jump with happiness, this bug is driving me insane!

Comment: What are the values for `right_side.width` and `right_side.height`?

Comment: Replace `row_instance.size_hint = (1, None)` with `row_instance.size_hint = (None, None)`

Comment: right_side is float layout in both directions
and the scrollable window is under a fixed widget(that is put there on startup) by fixed height
I tried your suggestion and added: 
    row_instance.width=self.ids.right_side.width
and it didn't help

Comment: Please post a print screen of the result.

Comment: the picture is a printscreen of how it looks it shows the relevant part all the other parts work fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the layout inside the screen.
Like in this example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

KV = """
ScreenManager:
    Screen:
        name: 'first'
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: "Test label screen1"
            Button:
                text:'go to other'
                on_press: root.current = 'other'

    Screen:
        name: 'other'
        on_enter: mybox.add_labels()
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            MyBox:
                id: mybox
            Button:
                size_hint: 1, 0.2
                text:'go to first'
                on_press: root.current = 'first'
"""

class MyBox(BoxLayout):

    def add_labels(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
        for i in range(10):
            self.add_widget(Button(text=str(i)))


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

MyApp().run()
```

Comment: sorry I wasnt clear
it does work and all widgets go into the screen successfully
the function:self.constr_widget just returns the specific widget 
the problem is the **positioning** 
they all just stack one ontop of eachother

Comment: @mgold You still need to put the layout inside the screen like I do. Not screen inside the layout